# Handle an array of inputs -React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, react-hooks

I have a table where I need to make a list of input elements. They will have a default value and you can change their value from max number(default value) to 0 or send this maxNumber. Next to input elements is send button. The Button will get value from the input element and send it to API. Here is part of my code:

```
const [valueInput,setValueInput]=React.useState(0);


         {array.map((x) => (
            <TableRow
            key={x.id}
            >
         <TableCell>{x.maxNumber}</TableCell>
               <TableCell>
              <input
                  key={x.id}
              value ={valueInput}
     
              onChange={ event => {
                 setValueInput(event.target.value);
              parseInt(event.target.value,valueInput)
               }}
              type="number"
              min="0"
              max= {x.maxNumber}
            />
                  <IconButton
                    key={x.id}
                    onClick={() => {
                      
                      team.setTeamNumber(x.id,valueInput);
                    }}>
                    <Check />
                  </IconButton>
          </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
))}
```

Can anyone help me how to set valueInput to be x.maxNumber - from the array, or any advice on how can I solve this without useState.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the table row with input into a separate component and have the input state there. Then pass the row id and the input value up to the parent component on the change. For example

```js
function TableRow({ id, inputValue, onInputChange }) {
  const [inputVal, setInputVal] = React.useState(inputValue);
  
  function handleInputChange(e) {
    setInputVal(e.target.value);
    onInputChange(id, e.target.value);
  }
  
  return (
    <tr>
      <td style={{ 'border': '1px solid black' }}>{inputValue}</td>
      <td style={{ 'border': '1px solid black' }}>
        <input type="number" value={inputVal} onChange={handleInputChange} />
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
}

function Table() {
  const rowsArr = [
    { id: '123', maxNum: 1 },
    { id: '456', maxNum: 2 }
  ];
  
  function handleInputChange(inputId, inputValue) {
    console.log(`Input with id ${inputId} has value ${inputValue}`);
   
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <table style={{ 'border': '1px solid black' }}>
        <tbody>
          {rowsArr.map((x) => <TableRow key={x.id} id={x.id} inputValue={x.maxNum} onInputChange={handleInputChange} />)}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {  
  return (
    <div>
      <Table />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```